# how to set a color to a WPF Datagrid with index?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a `DataGrid` in `WPF`, it was set with `ItemSource`. What I want is to color the `DataGridRow` with the given index. So far i did this,

```
DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)dgv_RStructure.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(int.Parse(id)); 
row.Background = (SolidColorBrush)(Converter.ConvertFrom(Color));
```

Only problem with this code is what ever the index I give, it colors that index and few more other indexes of the grid. I don't know why this happens, can any one help.

Comment: Have you tried styling the row in `XAML`? Try looking at [DataGridRowStyle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.rowstyle(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: It wont do the job in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it has to do with virtualization - it's reusing the DataGridRow that you changed the background of. You could turn virtualization off but if your ItemsSource has a lot of items then performance is going to suffer. Add VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard" to your DataGrid to turn off virtualization.

You could also do it with a Style, a DataTrigger and a Converter (and leave virtualization enabled).

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication6.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication6"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:GridRowConverter x:Key="GridRowConverter" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:ViewModel HighlightedIndex="5" />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Text="Highlighted Index" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding HighlightedIndex, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="5" />
        <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
            <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Value="true">
                            <DataTrigger.Binding>
                                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource GridRowConverter}">
                                    <Binding /> <!-- 'ViewData' item for this row -->
                                    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}" Path="ItemsSource" /> <!-- The list of items -->
                                    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}" Path="DataContext.HighlightedIndex" /> <!-- Index of item to highlight -->
                                </MultiBinding>
                            </DataTrigger.Binding>
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Yellow" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.RowStyle>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace WpfApplication6
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }

    public class ViewData : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propName = null)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
        }

        private string item;
        public string Item { get { return item; } set { item = value; OnPropertyChanged(); } }

        public ViewData(string s)
        {
            Item = s;
        }
    }
    public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propName = null)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
        }

        private ObservableCollection<ViewData> items;
        public ObservableCollection<ViewData> Items { get { return items; } set { items = value; OnPropertyChanged(); } }

        private int highlightedIndex;
        public int HighlightedIndex { get { return highlightedIndex; } set { highlightedIndex = value; OnPropertyChanged(); } }

        public ViewModel()
        {
            HighlightedIndex = -1;
            Items = new ObservableCollection<ViewData>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                Items.Add(new ViewData("Item " + i));
        }
    }

    public class GridRowConverter : IMultiValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (values.Length == 3)
            {
                var item = values[0] as ViewData;
                var items = values[1] as ObservableCollection<ViewData>;
                var idx = -1;
                if (values[2] is int)
                    idx = (int)values[2];
                if (idx >= 0
                    && items != null
                    && items.Count > idx
                    && items[idx] == item)
                        return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your code:

```
        // List of items from the datagrid
        var itemsSource = dgv_RStructure.ItemsSource as IList;

        // if such items exist
        if (itemsSource != null)
        {
            // Get each item as a datagrid row based on a selected index.
            var row = dgv_RStructure.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(itemsSource[int.Parse(id)]) as DataGridRow;

            // if the selected Datagrid Row exists
            if (row != null)
            {
                // change the row background to the preferred color.
                row.Background = Your_SolidColorBrush;
            }
        }
```

Here's an example application
1. XAML

```
    <Window x:Class="Solutions.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="80"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="30"></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="600"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <DataGrid x:Name="dgCustomers" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Customers}"/>

            <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Vertical">
                <ComboBox  Height="50" Margin="10" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Colours}" SelectedIndex="0" SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged">
                    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="50">
                                <Border Width="30" Height="30" Background="{Binding}" Margin="10"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Color}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ComboBox>
            </StackPanel>

            <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Button Margin="5" Width="50" Tag="0" Click="Button_Click">01</Button>
                <Button Margin="5" Width="50" Tag="1" Click="Button_Click">02</Button>
                <Button Margin="5" Width="50" Tag="2" Click="Button_Click">03</Button>
                <Button Margin="5" Width="50" Tag="3" Click="Button_Click">04</Button>
                <Button Margin="5" Width="50" Tag="4" Click="Button_Click">05</Button>
                <Button Margin="5" Width="50" Tag="5" Click="Button_Click">06</Button>
                <Button Margin="5" Width="50" Tag="6" Click="Button_Click">07</Button>
                <Button Margin="5" Width="50" Tag="7" Click="Button_Click">08</Button>
                <Button Margin="5" Width="50" Tag="8" Click="Button_Click">09</Button>
                <Button Margin="5" Width="50" Tag="9" Click="Button_Click">10</Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </Window>
```

2. CODE:

   ```
   using System;
   using System.Collections;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.Drawing;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Text;
   using System.Threading.Tasks;
   using System.Windows;
   using System.Windows.Controls;
   using System.Windows.Data;
   using System.Windows.Documents;
   using System.Windows.Input;
   using System.Windows.Media;
   using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
   using System.Windows.Navigation;
   using System.Windows.Shapes;

   namespace Solutions
   {
       /// <summary>
       /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
       /// </summary>
       public partial class MainWindow : Window
       {
           public MainWindow()
           {
               this.InitializeComponent();
               this.InitializeData();
               this.DataContext = this;
           }

           // Customers Sample Data and Colors
           private void InitializeData() 
           {
               // Sample Data: List of Customers
               this.Customers = new List<Customer>
               {
                   new Customer(){ CustomerID = 01, Code = "CST-00A-001", Name = "Name", Surname = "Surname", Telephone = "12345567890", Email = "customer@email.com"},
                   new Customer(){ CustomerID = 02, Code = "CST-00A-002", Name = "Name", Surname = "Surname", Telephone = "12345567890", Email = "customer@email.com"},
                   new Customer(){ CustomerID = 03, Code = "CST-00A-003", Name = "Name", Surname = "Surname", Telephone = "12345567890", Email = "customer@email.com"},
                   new Customer(){ CustomerID = 04, Code = "CST-00A-004", Name = "Name", Surname = "Surname", Telephone = "12345567890", Email = "customer@email.com"},
                   new Customer(){ CustomerID = 05, Code = "CST-00A-005", Name = "Name", Surname = "Surname", Telephone = "12345567890", Email = "customer@email.com"},
                   new Customer(){ CustomerID = 06, Code = "CST-00A-006", Name = "Name", Surname = "Surname", Telephone = "12345567890", Email = "customer@email.com"},
                   new Customer(){ CustomerID = 07, Code = "CST-00A-007", Name = "Name", Surname = "Surname", Telephone = "12345567890", Email = "customer@email.com"},
                   new Customer(){ CustomerID = 08, Code = "CST-00A-008", Name = "Name", Surname = "Surname", Telephone = "12345567890", Email = "customer@email.com"},
                   new Customer(){ CustomerID = 09, Code = "CST-00A-009", Name = "Name", Surname = "Surname", Telephone = "12345567890", Email = "customer@email.com"},
                   new Customer(){ CustomerID = 10, Code = "CST-00A-010", Name = "Name", Surname = "Surname", Telephone = "12345567890", Email = "customer@email.com"}
               };

               // Colors to be used as row backgrounds
               this.Colours = new List<SolidColorBrush> 
               {
                   new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red),
                   new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Orange),
                   new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow),
                   new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green),
                   new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue),
                   new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Indigo),
                   new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Violet)
               };          
           }


           // When selected color is changed.
           private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
           {
               // Set preferred color from combo-box selection
               ComboBox cb = sender as ComboBox;
               this.SelectedColor = cb.SelectedItem as SolidColorBrush;
           }

           // When a button is clicked
           private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
           {
               // Get the clicked button
               var btn = sender as Button;

               // use its tag property as a row index
               int rowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(btn.Tag);

               // Change the selected row background to the preferred color.
               this.ChangeRowBackground(rowIndex);
           }

           // Change the selected row background to the preferred color.
           private void ChangeRowBackground(int selectedIndex)
           {
               // List of items from the datagrid
               var itemsSource = dgCustomers.ItemsSource as IList;

               // if such items exist
               if (itemsSource != null)
               {
                   // Get each item as a datagrid row based on a selected index.
                   var row = dgCustomers.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(itemsSource[selectedIndex]) as DataGridRow;

                   // if the selected Datagrid Row exists
                   if (row != null)
                   {
                       // change the row background to the preferred color.
                       row.Background = SelectedColor;
                   }
               }
           }

           // Public Properties
           public IList<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
           public IList<SolidColorBrush> Colours { get; set; }
           public SolidColorBrush SelectedColor { get; set; }
       }

       //Customer Class
       public class Customer 
       {
           // Properties
           public int CustomerID { get; set; }
           public string Code { get; set; }
           public string Name { get; set; }
           public string Surname { get; set; }
           public string Telephone { get; set; }
           public string Email { get; set; }
       }
   }
   ```
3. SCREEN SHOT (1):

[image: Select preferred color from the Combo-Box]

4. SCREEN SHOT (2)

[image: Use the buttons to Change Row Background to the selected preferred color]

5. SCREEN SHOT (3)

[image: Other color can be assigned to different rows.]

Good-luck!